# java spring aop: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut LoginMethod

Tags: java, spring, aop

I've designed a database application and am now having trouble handling exceptions when connecting to the database using spring aop. The classes involved are shown below:

LoginInterface.java

```java
interface LoginInterface {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("LoginApp.xml");
    Login login = (Login) context.getBean("Login");
    login.loginMethod(username,password);
}
```

Login.java

```java
class Login {
    public void loginMethod(String username, char[] pwd) throws ClassNOtFoundException, SQLException{
         ...
    }
}
```

LoginProfiler.java

```java
@Aspect
public class LoginProfiler {

    @Pointcut("execution(* dbapp.Login.loginMethod(String, char[])throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.sql.SQLException)")
    public void loginMethod() {
    }

    @Around("loginMethod()")
    public void handleException(final ProceedingJoinPoint pJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            pJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if ((e.getCause().toString()).contains("UnknownHostException"))
                System.out.println("Unknown Host ");
            else if ((e.getCause().toString()).contains("ConnectException"))
                System.out.println("Connection Problem ");
        }
    }
}
```

LoginApp.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
    default-destroy-method="destroy"
    default-init-method="afterPropertiesSet"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- Enable the @AspectJ support -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="LoginProfiler" class="dbapp.LoginProfiler" />
    <bean id="Login" class="dbapp.Login" />
</beans>
```

I've got the following exception:

```
Erg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Login' defined in class path resource [LoginApp.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut LoginMethod
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at 
    ..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut LoginMethod
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:206)
    at
```

Comment: can pls anyone hlep me here, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
@Aspect
public class LoginProfiler {

       @Pointcut("execution(* dbapp.Login.loginMethod(String, char[])throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.sql.SQLException)")
       public void loginMethod(){}

       @AfterThrowing("loginMethod()")
        public void handleException(final JoinPoint joinPoint){ 
               System.out.println("Am able to Handle");
        }
}
```

or

```
@Aspect
public class LoginProfiler {

       @AfterThrowing("execution(* dbapp.Login.loginMethod(String, char[])throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.sql.SQLException)")
        public void handleException(final JoinPoint joinPoint){ 
               System.out.println("Am able to Handle");
        }
}
```

Also it would be better if you spend some time learning about spring-aop. From your question it looks like you really don't understand AOP. You are trying to cut and paste from some sample code.

Comment: sorry, yes am new to this, i worked few basic things which went fine, when i tried with the afterthowing i got stucked, I only did this coding.

Comment: sorry i tried with change, its giving new exception Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Login' defined in class path resource [LoginApp.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: SQLException [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]   I tried with throwing parameter but dint worked same error

Comment: The exception names in the pointcut expression should be fully qualified. Updated my answer.  You can also remove the throws clause from the pointcut expression and try.